# Where does the mass go in Clausius-Clapeyron approximation for ideal gases?

Tags: thermodynamics, mass, ideal-gas, phase-diagram

I am currently studying [Clausius-Clapeyron equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius%E2%80%93Clapeyron_relation)  at university. One of the proposed problems asked us to find the latent heat of vaporisation of camphor using ideal gas laws. In the solution by my professor the Clausius-Clapeyron equation $dP/dT=L/T\Delta v$ is simplified to $dP/dT=L/Tv_{gas}$ which makes sense because vapour has much greater specific volume than liquid. Then he proceeds to use ideal gas law $PV=nRT$ to get $V=nRT/P$ and plugging that $V$ in place of $v_{gas}$ to find $dP/dT=lP/T^2R$, where $l$ is the molar specific latent heat of vaporisation, i.e. $l=L/n$.
I don't understand why plugging $V$ in place of $v_{gas}$ is allowed, as $v_{gas}$ is defined as the specific volume, i.e. $v_{gas}=V/m$, while $V$ is just... $V$, not divided by the mass. My question is where did that mass go? Or better, why is this valid?

Comment: The number of moles of gas cancel out, because l is the heat of vaporization per mole and v is the volume per mole.

Comment: Oh okay. But he defined v as V/m, that is why I am a bit confused. Are they interchangeable? I would assume the result would be different, as mass and number of moles do not necessarily have the same value.

Comment: mass and moles are proportional.  Mass is equal to moles multiplied by molar mass.  So l and v are per unit mass or per mole.  It doesn't matter as long as we are consistent.